# DataGrip diagram: remove labels from arrows?

Tags: postgresql, diagram, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

When DataGrip draws a diagram ("organic" layout, if that matters), the arrows between tables are labelled.  Sometimes the labels add only clutter, not meaning.

How can the labels be removed?

[image: example of unhelpful labels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you need to enable access through the keyboard for this type of features .. see the following photo:

[image]

```
1- Ctrl+S
2- Search Show Edge Labels
3- Define a Keymap
```

or the easy way:

Right click in an area where a table does not appear in the diagram, and click `Show Edge Labels`

[image]